# Can I put images in the same directory as my markdown with NuxtJS Content?

Tags: frontend, nuxt.js, static-site

I'm trying to make a static markdown site with Nuxt.js (and the `@nuxtjs/content` plugin) and I'd like my authors to be able to keep the images for a particular post in the same directory as the markdown. It'd be a lot easier for them to organize the content that way instead of splitting it between the `content` and `assets` directories.

The images that are more widely useful across the site can go in `assets` of course, but there's lots of images that will only ever be applicable to one post.

I've tried all of the following, and they all create an `<img>` with the given `src`, but the image doesn't exist at that url. Instead I get a 1x1 gif.

```
![alt text](bwa_059.png)

![alt text](./bwa_059.png)

<img src="bwa_059.png"/>

<img src="./bwa_059.png"/>
```

Is this possible with Nuxt? I'm kinda surprised I haven't found anyone else even asking about this, since it seems like an author-friendly way of organizing the content.

Comment: You might find a couple of similar issues in the Nuxt content GH issues. E.g. [this one](https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/651) and the reference in there.

Comment: @Peter9192 Good pointer but yeah I've checked. The one that references ([#106](https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/106)) I've actually posted in.

Answer (score 1):

uhm sorry to ask this but how can you include the images, if they are stored in the assets folder? I am failing terribly at this and don't really know why..

I was also surprised how little comes up on this topic..